# How to set Active namespace in Kubernetes using python

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am working on kubernetes API on python. We use the same namespace everytime. So I thought of setting the name form python itself. But I could not find any relevant documentation on how to set active namespace in kuebernetes API in python. Can anyone help me here? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

you can use python kubernetes client https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python . and use kubernetes's native command through client .

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=development
```